# Windows Azure Mobile Service: dont insert more than once the same data

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-7, azure, windows-phone-8, azure-mobile-services

I have an application in windows phone and make registration with facebook and I store some data in a table, however, a single user it is being stored more than once in the table. I tried (getting the fb-id) check on the table if a record with that fb-id, but before re registrare l new user should check whether there is, however, such as asynchronous methods there is no order and always first executes the query insertion, as I can resolve this?

client side (limited)

```
                    await App.MobileService.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook);
                    Message = string.Format("User Authenticate - {0}", App.MobileService.CurrentUser.UserId);

                    //***** Get fb info
                    var userId = App.MobileService.CurrentUser.UserId;
                    var facebookId = userId.Substring(userId.IndexOf(':') + 1);
                    var client = new HttpClient();
                    var fbUser = await client.GetAsync("https://graph.facebook.com/" + facebookId);
                    var response = await fbUser.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var jo = JObject.Parse(response);
                    var FbidUser = jo.GetValue("id");
                    var userName = jo.GetValue("name");
                    var genero = jo.GetValue("gender");
```

but, i slould be do at server client, but how to insert info data one time, i mean, Check the record in the table before inserting. 
Server side Azure:

```
function insert(item, user, request) 
{
  item.UserName = "<unknown>"; // default
  var identities = user.getIdentities();
  var req = require('request');

  if (identities.facebook)
  {
    var fbAccessToken = identities.facebook.accessToken;
    var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' + fbAccessToken;

    req(url, function (err, resp, body)
    {
        if (err || resp.statusCode !== 200)
        {
            console.error('Error sending data to FB Graph API: ', err);
            request.respond(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, body);
        }
        else 
        {
            try 
            {
                var userData = JSON.parse(body);
                item.UserName = userData.name;
                request.execute();
            } catch (ex) 
            {
                console.error('Error parsing response from FB Graph API: ', ex);
                request.respond(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex);
            }
        }
    });

  }
}
```

according to the above code, i have a second question, in the developer center on facebook, I have access to email and photos (my application), I guess **userData** variable contains this information?, how do I access it?, how to call those properties where the rest of the information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is to prevent two items for users with the same name to be inserted, the easiest way would be to not use the name at all, but instead use the FB id (after all, it's possible that two different people have the same name). That you can do with the script below:

```
function insert(item, user, request) 
{
    item.UserId = user.userId;
    var currentTable = tables.current;
    currentTable.where({ UserId: user.userId }).read({
        success: function(results) {
            if (results.length > 0) {
                // an item with that user id already exists in the table
                request.respond(400, 
                    { error: 'item already in the table' });
            } else {
                // new user, can insert it here
                request.execute();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Now, if you really want to use the user **name** as the "key" for your table, you can do something similar as well:

```
function insert(item, user, request) 
{
  item.UserName = "<unknown>"; // default
  var identities = user.getIdentities();
  var req = require('request');
  var currentTable = tables.current;

  if (identities.facebook)
  {
    var fbAccessToken = identities.facebook.accessToken;
    var url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=' + fbAccessToken;

    req(url, function (err, resp, body)
    {
        if (err || resp.statusCode !== 200)
        {
            console.error('Error sending data to FB Graph API: ', err);
            request.respond(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, body);
        } else {
            try {
                var userData = JSON.parse(body);
                item.UserName = userData.name;
                currentTable.where({ UserName: item.UserName }).read({
                    success: function(results) {
                        if (results.length > 0) {
                            request.respond(statusCodes.BAD_REQUEST,
                                { error: 'Name already in the table' });
                        } else {
                            request.execute();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } catch (ex) {
                console.error('Error parsing response from FB Graph API: ', ex);
                request.respond(statusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, ex);
            }
        }
    });

  }
}
```

Comment: Great! response... so, how to get additionally info from "userData", i mean, in the client side, i need to debug my app to know and get de nodes of Json file, so, in azure, how to know the name of this nodes ? (images, photos, about etc). the name of nodes are equal name from Graph api explorer of fb ?

Comment: When logging in with the "simple" authentication (when the client calls `LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.Facebook)`, the runtime will ask FB only for some basic information about the user - which is what you get when calling the graph.facebook.com/me with the access token. If you want more information, you should login with a Facebook SDK for your platforms, where you can request additional information.